# replace value at specific coordinate with mean of sorrounding cells in Xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I've been trying to replace the value of a cell (meaning, a point with an specific latitude and longitude) in a xarray dataset. The coordinares of my Dataset are lon, lat and time. I want to replace the value of certain lat and lon with the mean of the adjacent cells across time.

So far I've managed to replace it with an scalar (e.g. `ds.loc[{'lon': long, 'lat': lat}]['qtot'] = 1`, but when I try to replace it with an array or dataarray it seems ok but it does not update the value in the original dataset. I've tried the following expressions:

```
ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}]['qtot'] = ds.loc[{'lon': slice(lon-0.5, lon+0.5), 'lat': slice(lat+0.5, lat-0.5)}]['qtot'].mean(['lat', 'lon'])

ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}]['qtot'].values = ds.loc[{'lon': slice(lon-0.5, lon+0.5), 'lat': slice(lat+0.5, lat-0.5)}]['qtot'].mean(['lat', 'lon']).values
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: `ds.loc[{'lat': slice(y1, y2), 'lon': slice(x1, x2)}]['qtot'] = 1` doesn't work for me, whereas with `ds['qtot'].loc[{'lat': slice(y1, y2), 'lon': slice(x1, x2)}] = 1` (accessing the variable prior to slicing with `.loc`), the assignment works fine. The same is true with assigning arrays rather than scalars. Does that address the issue for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xarray, you can use `.loc[]` to assign values to DataArrays or Datasets:

```py
# all of these work
ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = 1
ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}].mean()
ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = 1
ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}].mean()
```

However, using `.loc[]` to get a view into a subset a Dataset, then referencing a variable from the view, then assigning to *that* does seem to break xarray's assignment handling:

```py
# both of these have no effect
ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}]['qstat'] = 1
ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}]['qstat'] = ds.loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}]['qstat'].mean()
```

This could possibly be a bug, but it's not a pattern I've seen used often, and the more standard way of referencing an entire variable prior to slicing & assignment does work.

This seems like it could be analagous to the pandas [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) case, where a chained assignment along the lines of `df.loc[slicer][colname] = 1` does not modify `df`.

Comment: thanks Michael! I tried to use ```ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}].mean()``` to achieve what I wanted: ```ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': slice(lon+1, lon-1), 'lat': slice(lat+1, lat-1)}].mean(['lon', 'lat'])´´´, but it does not work. I understand that maybe this action is not commonly used, but what is strange is that Xarray does not print any warning.

Comment: update: this formulation works! ```ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': lon, 'lat': lat}] = ds['qstat'].loc[{'lon': slice(lon+1, lon-1), 'lat': slice(lat+1, lat-1)}].mean(['lon', 'lat'])´´´ Thanks Michael!

Comment: huh - just FYI the order of your arguments to `slice` does matter. If your coordinate is in descending order (this occurs often for lat, but not lon in my experience) then you'll need to use `slice(lat + 1, lat - 1)` but `slice(lon - 1, lon + 1)`

Comment: and re: printing warnings - there's not really a way for xarray to know that you're doing this without building a whole infrastructure for determining whether you're assigning to a veiw or a whole array, and as far as I understand, this wouldn't work at all for some backends. the problem is that you are making a valid assignment, but you're doing it to a temporary object.